# Duplicate particle system (not linked)

Tags: particles

I want to duplicate particle system(shift D), and make different Render objects. But after i change Object, it makes the same change in both particle systems ( original and duplicated). Somehow it's still linked.. ?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think i found solution. It's enough to click on this icon near Particle Settings, and it makes particle different from others.

[image]