# Changes on one particle system affect other particle systems

Tags: particles

I'm making a rabbit, so I used a particle system to make the fur. I made multiple systems by making vertex groups but I faced a problem: when I started to edit the particle system, all the systems make the same changes. For example, I clumped my first particle systems by 1.000 all of them  have the same changes. Can anyone help me thank you

Here's a picture
[image]

Comment: In the future please use a more focused title for the question, and use punctuation to make your questions clearer...

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10822/duplicate-particle-system-not-linked ?